# How to use Dropbox-sdk-js in the browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify, html, dropbox-sdk-js

I have been trying to get the [dropbox-sdk-js](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js) running in the browser. The sdk is developped for node.

What I need is to include the sdk in a `<script>` tag and start using the SDK in JS.

I tried Webpack and Browserify. But none of them seem to unentangle the `Dropbox` js object from `require` for me to use in the browser. Simply `requre` is undefined both after webpack and browsify.

**-- Reproduce --**

1. Go to the root folder of the repo and execute `webpack`. This will read `webpack.config.js` and create `dropbox-sdk.js` in `dist` folder
2. Include the file in my script `<script src="dropbox-sdk.js"></script>`
3. Undefined error come when I try to execute `var Dropbox = require('dropbox');`

The script is guaranteed to be included correctly. Even tried to use a precompiled one from [this](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropbox.js/2.4.0/dropbox-sdk.js) CDN.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The example under https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js/blob/master/examples/basic/index.html does not use `require('dropbox')`

Comment: Yes. But these examples can only be run in node. Also when I tried without "requre" then the next error is "Dropbox" is not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the dropbox-sdk in browser you either have to use

- with a module bundler like **webpack** or **browserify**
- or to avoid the module builder you can reference **/dropbox/dist/dropbox-sdk.min.js** in the node_modules